# Store the object as a key in map

Tags: java, hashmap

While storing multiple object as a key in Map even if i am using generics.

```
ArrayList<String> fruitlist = new ArrayList<>();    
fruitlist.addAll(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Grapes"));           
ArrayList<String> vegglist = new ArrayList<>();    
vegglist.addAll(Arrays.asList("Potato", "Squash", "Beans"));

Map<String, ArrayList<String>> productsMap = new HashMap<>();           
Allien a = new Allien(101, "John");  //creted sperated Allien class and constructor    
Predator p = new Predator(102, "Lisa"); // creted sperated Predator class and constructor           
productsMap.put(a, fruitlist); //compile time error change type a as String    
productsMap.put(p, vegglist);  // same error
```

Please suggest where i am wrong to put multiple object as a key,

Comment: The key of your Map is String, so you can only put Strings as keys.

Comment: You've specified that your map key is a string, not an `Allien` or a `Predator`. How did you expect that to work? Perhaps you want `Map<Object, ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: Thank you ,its a silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Use an Object as a key in HashMap, the key Object must override the **hashCode** and **equals** method.

See below sample, it give output "this is person 100":

```
public class HashMapSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<Person, String>();
        map.put(new Person(100, "name 100"),  "this is person 100");
        map.put(new Person(200, "name 200"),  "this is person 200");

        Person key = new Person(100, "new name 100");
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println(map.get(key));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    int id;
    String name;

    public Person (int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name =  name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Person) {
            Person person = (Person) obj;
            return person.id == this.id;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, just to add - it is necessary to override the hashCode() method whenever equals() method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode() method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes

Answer (score 1):

You have specified  your Map key as string but required an object. you need to change your map declaration like below

```
Map<Object, ArrayList<String>> productsMap = new HashMap<>();
```